# Why is kinetic energy denoted by the letter $T$ in quantum mechanics?

Tags: energy, terminology, notation

Kinetic energy is often written as $K$, $KE$ or $E_k$. Where does $T$ come from in quantum mechanics? Why and how did it come to be different?

Comment: I thought that it might be because it was close to $U$ and $V$ in the alphabetical order. It was just a speculation of mine, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’m pretty sure Lagrange started this, in *Méchanique analitique* (1788, [p. 224](http://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/9874626); 1809, [p. 263](http://www.archive.org/stream/mmoiresdelinst09inst#page/263); 1811, [p. 311](http://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/6303351); 1815, [p. 2](http://www.e-rara.ch/zut/content/pageview/6303472)): his predecessors mostly worked with the *vis viva* ($=2T$) instead.

(As to why he chose the letter  $T$, no idea. Words like kinetic, energy, work, appeared only [later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#History_and_etymology).)

Answer (score 6):

Gaspard-Gustave Coriolis and Jean-Victor Poncelet used the name "quantité de travail" (quantity of work) and "travail mécanique" (mechanical work) to denote the kinetic energy. I guess that this (the term "travail") could be the origin of the symbol $T$. See at the end of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis_viva

(Be patient for my superficiality, I am very far from being a historian of science, I am just a mathematical physicist and this post migrated here from PSE.)

Comment: Sorry it seems I took I mistake! I am correcting my answer.

Comment: D. Bernoulli is mentioned in Wikipedia text, but not for using $T$.

Comment: I forgive your mistake. I have to admit mathematical physics is an intriguing distraction. If you happen to be in Trieste, there's a beer and some company waiting :-)